# Response body is null, status is 200

Tags: angular, http, httpclient

I'm using Angular's new HttpClient for requests. When I was using the old http, my component returned the body text just fine, but now the body text is null. I can't figure it out, the server is sending it, but i'm always receiving null as the body.

every other part of the response is normal, status 200  etc. Both the put and the delete expect a plain text success message. I have also tried using the .body method to get the body text, and that returns null as well.

service:

```
constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

    sendAllow(country, allow) {
        if (allow === 1) {
            return this.http.put(`http://${this.address}/rest/geodrop/config/` +
                                 `${country}`, { observe: 'response' });
        } else {
            return this.http.delete(`http://${this.address}/rest/geodrop/config/` +
                                    `${country}`, { observe: 'response' });
        }
    }
```

component:

```
this.whiteListService.sendAllow(a, b)
            .subscribe(
                (response) => console.log(response),
                (error) => {
                    console.log(error);
                }
        );
```

Comment: There are 2 HTTP requests, one `PUT` and one `DELETE`, which one returned unexpected `null` text? What is the expected body text?

Comment: both are supposed to return a plain text success message for put or delete

Comment: Is the URL public? Can we try to make the `PUT` or `DELETE` request?

Comment: The URL is not public, I was hoping this was a common issue. I'm not sure why it worked using http, and not httpClient. I will keep this thread updated

Comment: When I do a curl request to test the node, I am getting the textual response in my terminal. I dont understand

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The problem is Angular is expecting a json response. change the response to type text like so:

```
return this.http.put(`http://${this.address}/rest/geodrop/config/` +
                     `${country}`, { responseType: 'text', observe: 'response' });
```

Comment: glad it helped haha. I thought when I posted it, it was a stupid question because it got no traction. I figured it out myself, and months later it's helping people. good to know it's not useless

Comment: thank you for this scratching my head after changing accept/content headers to 'text' but getting a null in the subscription!

Comment: sure thing @MichaelHarper