# Angular HttpClient returns null value for response of zero

Tags: angular, angular-httpclient

I have migrated my Angular 4 service from old Http to the new HttpClient. A request that is returning plain zero `0` as the response, is returning an observable with `null`.

The request:

```
return this.httpClient.get(url, options)
  .do(res => console.log('service returns', res)) as Observable<number>;
```

will console log `null`, but when I open that request in devtools > Network, I see that the server responded with `0`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your not alone, I'm having almost the same problem... Although with post instead of a get, I get back a null as well, even though the network debugging tools are showing that the backend service is sending the info in the response as expected.

Comment: same here, it's also returning null if response is false.

Answer (score 1):

HttpClient expects JSON object by default. As, you are responding with just the value, it returns the value as null(no json object!)

Got the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/46081328/3133446

Just change the '`responseType`' to '`text`' when sending the request.